# UITableView cell will not loade img with setImageWithUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, afnetworking

Iam trying to get images with AFNetworking+UIImageview method setImageWithURL:

The code is this

```
//Get the url from data
NSArray *images = [data valueForKey:@"images"];
NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[images valueForKey:@"mobile"]];
imgUrl = [imgUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
imgUrl = [imgUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
imgUrl = [imgUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSString* webStringURL = [imgUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];

//create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load cell with image
[cell.imgvwBackground setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackLogo"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %ld \n %@",(long)[response statusCode], error);
}];
```

The error iam getting is this:

```
2015-02-28 20:18:53.822 Diggit[964:60b] RESPONSE: 0 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x16694490 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(https://images.bowntycdn.net/images/deals/mobile/24013997/groupon-dk-herremode-loom-joggingbukser-levering-gratis.jpg), NSErrorFailingURLKey=(https://images.bowntycdn.net/images/deals/mobile/24013997/groupon-dk-herremode-loom-joggingbukser-levering-gratis.jpg), NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x166931c0 "unsupported URL"}
```

So the image link iam getting the image from is this: https://images.bowntycdn.net/images/deals/mobile/24013997/groupon-dk-herremode-loom-joggingbukser-levering-gratis.jpg
But it cant recognise it as a link.

I have tried with

```
[cell.imgvwBackground setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
```

But the image wont work as well. Hope you guys can help

Comment: Seems like something is up with our NSURL. I'd break apart your request and print our the contents of imgURL, and NSURL. It's possible you have some unexpected formatting (spaces etc) in there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Glen, it helped me solve my problem. The images in the json was a array, so the link it returned was wrappen in (). I have fixed it with
     NSString *imgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[images objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"original_size"]];

Comment: check image url link is it correct or not . NSLog url and open same link in chrome check is it opening or not